Applying Two Different Textures with Two Different Materials on the Same Mesh in Three.js/blender
I am working on a project where the user can cusotmise his/her shoes. I want them to color the individual parts which is easy to build (each part of the shoe is its own mesh). 1,2 and 3 are separate meshes in the model
secondly, I want them to add any character or picture on their shoes like shown below. I've planned to achieve it using fabric js, how do i seamlessly apply the image across multiple meshes?
an attempt shown in PS
How do I apply image to different meshes seamlessly?

For a general overview, take a look at this. In vanilla, name the individual parts of the shoe in Blender, and grab them by name and work with them. As for the other two points, it sounds... serious. And you would have to provide more details in these questions. Do you mean re-create geometry? BTW what do you mean by painting? Mapping?

Ive edited the questions, hope im clear enough!

As I wrote in the comment, you need to create and appropriately name the parts of the model you are interested in in Blender(or other one), and then retrieve them. Then map the parts of the shoe that interest you, because that's how I understood your question. My understanding of it is that you want to sort of apply the texture to the separate parts of the shoe as a whole texture. But if I understood it wrong, and you only want to apply texture to specific parts of the shoe, you proceed in the same way. In other words, you map individual names in an array, or the entire array. A very important thing, which is visible in my example, the model must have UVs. If it doesn't have them, the texture will look like above. It's best to deal with this at the Blender stage. You can do it procedurally or with a custom shader([will be harder] => especially when model has skeleton). But it's a more complicated process than Blender.


<script type="importmap">
  {
"imports": {
  "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.166.0/build/three.module.js",
  "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.166.0/examples/jsm/"
}
  }
</script>

<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';


const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
camera.position.z = 5;

const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
scene.add(ambientLight);
const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
directionalLight.position.set(10, 10, 10).normalize();
scene.add(directionalLight);

//let say these are parts of your shoe, which you interested to map
const partsOfRobo = ["FootL_1", "Torso_2", "Torso_3"];
const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const texture = textureLoader.load('https://media.craiyon.com/2023-11-26/2ets6-v1SVGOdKAtPxmlMw.webp');
texture.flipY = false;

const loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/models/gltf/RobotExpressive/RobotExpressive.glb', function (gltf) {
  const model = gltf.scene;
  model.position.set(0, -2, 0);
  model.traverse((child) => {
    if (child.isMesh) {
      const geometry = child.geometry;
      const hasUVs = geometry.attributes.uv !== undefined;
      console.log(`${child.name} ${hasUVs ? ' UVs.' : ' UVs.'}`);

      if (partsOfRobo.includes(child.name)) {
        child.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ map: texture });
      }
    }
  });
  scene.add(model);
  animate();
});

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
});

</script>




I think your suggestion would work but i am having hell of a time trying to get the UVs of islands aligned perfectly. I have posted a question about the issue I'm facing could you tell me if i am in the right path at least(in respect to blender and UVs). https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/322619/how-to-achieve-seamless-uvs-of-multple-meshes?noredirect=1#comment562711_322619
